# Java ProgressBar with HTTP Upload don't update

Tags: java, swing, file-upload, java-io, jprogressbar

I want my `jProgressBar` to update its value during `HTTP File Upload`.
I'm new to Java and I'm not sure I'm doing the right things, here's my code:

```
private static final String Boundary = "--7d021a37605f0";

public void upload(URL url, File f) throws Exception
{
    HttpURLConnection theUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    theUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    theUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    theUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    theUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);

    theUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="
            + Boundary);

    DataOutputStream httpOut = new DataOutputStream(theUrlConnection.getOutputStream());


        String str = "--" + Boundary + "\r\n"
                   + "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"file1\"; filename=\"" + f.getName() + "\"\r\n"
                   + "Content-Type: image/png\r\n"
                   + "\r\n";

        httpOut.write(str.getBytes());

        FileInputStream uploadFileReader = new FileInputStream(f);
        int numBytesToRead = 1024;
        int availableBytesToRead;
        jProgressBar1.setMaximum(uploadFileReader.available());
        while ((availableBytesToRead = uploadFileReader.available()) > 0)
        {
            jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getMaximum() - availableBytesToRead);
            byte[] bufferBytesRead;
            bufferBytesRead = availableBytesToRead >= numBytesToRead ? new byte[numBytesToRead]
                    : new byte[availableBytesToRead];
            uploadFileReader.read(bufferBytesRead);
            httpOut.write(bufferBytesRead);
            httpOut.flush();
        }
        httpOut.write(("--" + Boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());

    httpOut.flush();
    httpOut.close();

    // read & parse the response
    InputStream is = theUrlConnection.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] respBuffer = new byte[4096];
    while (is.read(respBuffer) >= 0)
    {
        response.append(new String(respBuffer).trim());
    }
    is.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

Is this line `jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getMaximum() - availableBytesToRead);` correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second @Marko Topolnic's suggestion of using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)  , Have a look at these useful links to get  you further on *Howto* ,

1. [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)
2. [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
3. [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

and an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/977676) by @trashgod.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you and @Marko Topolnic ! Your example was very useful, I put my function in an independent worker and that worked !

Answer (score 6):

Something like one in every 30 questions tagged `java` here has the same solution as yours. You are doing all your work inside an event handler, which means that it's happening on the Event Dispatch Thread -- and blocks all further GUI updates until it's over. You must use a `SwingWorker` and delegate your work to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering, but how can I fetch the upload progress from the worker please ?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code that fails to compile, or at runtime, do you have problems with sharing the reference to `jProgressBar1` to the other thread...?